# How to read value of input signal ARM microcontroller?

Tags: assembly, serial-port, arm, embedded

I want to write a code in assembly that checks if a button is pushed. I imagine the button has to be connected to a pin. The problem is that, even though I searched in the internet, I cannot find out the basic commands in assembly of how to define and check a signal in a port.

Could someone give me a simple example? Like "if signal in port10 is high, then... " in assembly code.
Thanks in advance and I am sorry if my question is very simple or not well defined as I am newbie in assembly language.
I am using the [MKL25Z4](https://developer.mbed.org/platforms/KL25Z/) microcontroller.

Comment: You need to look into the datasheet for that microcontroller. Typically, there is a memory-mapped register somewhere that you can read to find out if a button has been pressed.

Comment: Look at the software examples for the KL25Z freedom board.

Answer (score 3):

ARM do not make micrcontrollers; rather microcontroller vendors licence ARM architecture.  GPIO is not part of that ARM architecture and will be vendor specific; you need to consult the vendor's documentation for the part you are using.

Invariably however the GPIO will present itself as memory mapped I/O registers and as such accessing them is simply a matter of reading and writing the appropriate addresses.  There are no specific I/O instructions on ARM - everything is memory mapped.  As such it is also unnecessary to do this in assembler; in C or C++ for example, you can simply de-reference the address to access a peripheral register.